# Record conversation in bot with Connect/Lex

Tags: aws-lex, amazon-connect

I have a bot in Amazon Lex and I’m using Connect to allow to talk to it through the phone. We want to be able to generate a log of the calls with the recording.

The problem we are having is that we enable the option `Enable call recording` in Amazon Connect, but never see the recordings on S3 after making calls.

Is it needed to enable something else apart from that option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `Enable call recording` only works when there is an agent on the other side and it won't work with a bot in Lex.

What you can do is enable live media streaming. Under the section `Live media streaming` in the configuration of your Connect instance you will see the option `Enable live media streaming`. Then, in your Connect flow you need to add blocks to start live streaming (usually after the call started) and then to close the streaming (before the end of the call).

Once you do that, you will be able to see the recording in Kinesis, where you can download them or use the API to retrieve them (you should check the docs for Kinesis regarding that).

Once important thing is that only what the caller says gets recorded. What the bot says is not recorded.